# What is the best Option for Salesforce Customer Community Mobile App?

Tags: salesforce1-app, customer-community, mobile

We wanted to know what is the best options for providing a mobile app which is based on customer community. We have explored few options (mentioned below) but haven't been satisfied with the various issues present.

1. Salesforce 1 App: While it comes out of the box and works well, it has 2 major issues for customer. The branding is Salesforce (the customer will have to download Salesforce app from the app store) and while logging in for the first time, he will have to change the login URL to community URL. This is far from ideal experience for a customer.
2. MySalesforce App: This is an addon feature of Salesforce and is an ideal experience for a customer. It provides customer branding and separate app on app store in the name of customer. So from the customer experience, this looks good. However, while working with a customer on this recently, we encountered few issues which made us rethink the approach

   - One of the issues we found was that you can't upload files using it. If you are a community user and you are using MySalesforce app, you can't upload files.
   - Since this is a new addon from salesforce, the support from Salesforce has been very slow. For a bug in the app, it took them around 4-6 months to fix. This puts a risk on the app strategy because if there is an issue in the future, we are dependent on Salesforce support to fix it.
3. Custom Developed App: This would be build using Mobile SDKs from Salesforce and/or APIs from Salesforce. This puts the customer in complete control of the app and allows 100% customisation as per customer needs. The issue here is that today most of the customers are mobile centric and the browser usage of the app would be limited/low compared to mobile usage. In such a scenario, does it make sense to enable communities when the majority of the user base would not use it?

What are your thoughts? Is there an option that isn't explored here and we are missing out?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this is a great question, and looks like you've already put a lot of thought into this. Some time ago we wrote a [blog](http://www.mobilecaddy.net/making-right-choice-mobile-salesforce-community-applications/) on this (before MySalesforce or Mobile Publisher was a thing, so it's a bit dated now).

In my opinion, as with most dev questions, the answer is "it depends". Having a checklist of "must have" requirements is generally where we start, and if one of the options can't meet that requirement then it's counted out. For example, we work with a lot of folk where 100% offline is needed, and therefore it has to be a custom app, or the customer wants their own branding or to use their own MDM, so in this case you again need to rule out Salesforce Mobile App.

I believe that PWAs are also an option, and should be considered, as they'll cover your browser users too. These do have their own limitations (reduced access to hardware APIs, etc) and complications but should probably be thought about too... even if they're ruled out in favour of custom apps.

If you do go down the custom route then there are a couple of options, and apps available on AppX to help (as it's a tricky business), such as our MobileCaddy offering - which is a full app lifecycle framework that includes support for 100% custom UI, and full offline support (out of the box).

Comment: Thank you, Todd. That's great information.